# Fourier series of oscillation in form $\cos(2 \pi \frac{k}{T}+\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab, mathematica

I would like to calculate the fourier coefficients of $\cos(2 \pi \frac{k}{T}+\phi)$ where $T \in \mathbb{N}$ is the period and is arbitrary but fixed, $k \in [1, N-1]$ is the number of oscillations per period and $\phi \in [0, 2\pi[$ the phase.

I have rewritten my function as a complex exponential function:

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x(k, \phi, t) &= \cos\left(2 \pi \frac{k}{T} t + \phi\right) \\
     &= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\left(2 \pi \frac{k}{T} t + \phi\right)}
      + \mathrm{e}^{-i\left(2 \pi \frac{k}{T} t + \phi\right)}}{2} \\
     &= \left(\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{e}^{i \phi}\right) \mathrm{e}^{i2 \pi \frac{k}{T} t}
      + \left(\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{e}^{-i \phi}\right) \mathrm{e}^{-i2 \pi \frac{k}{T} t}
\end{split}
\end{align}

I then calculated my coefficients $c_n$ as:

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
c_n &= \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} x(k, \phi, t)  \mathrm{e}^{-i n \frac{2\pi}{T}t} dt \\
    &= \frac{1}{2T} \left( \mathrm{e}^{i \phi} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}  \mathrm{e}^{i 2 \pi \frac{k - n}{T} t} dt
        + \mathrm{e}^{-i \phi} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} \mathrm{e}^{-i 2 \pi \frac{k + n}{T} t} dt \right)
\end{split}
\end{align}

I evaluated the integrals with $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$:
\begin{align*}
I_1 &= \int \mathrm{e}^{i 2 \pi \frac{k - n}{T} t} dt\\
    &= \frac{-iT}{2 \pi (k - n)} \mathrm{e}^{i 2 \pi \frac{k - n}{T} t}
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
I_1(t) \Bigr|_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} &= \frac{-iT}{2 \pi (k - n)} \left( \mathrm{e}^{i \pi \left( k - n \right)} - \mathrm{e}^{-i \pi \left( k - n \right)} \right) \\
 &= T \frac{\sin\left(\pi \left(k - n\right)\right)}{\pi (k - n)}
  = T \operatorname{sinc}\left(k-n\right)
\end{split}
\end{align}

And analog the other integral as $T \operatorname{sinc}\left(k+n\right)$.

I then get my coefficients $c_n$:
\begin{align}
c_n = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{i \phi} \operatorname{sinc}\left(k-n\right)
        + \mathrm{e}^{-i \phi} \operatorname{sinc}\left(k+n\right) \right)
\end{align}

I [tested](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierCoefficient%5Bcos%288.3*t%2B0.3%29%2Ct%2C9%5D-1%2F2*%28exp%28i*0.3%29*sinc%28%289-8.3%29*pi%29%2Bexp%28-i*0.3%29*sinc%28%289%2B8.3%29*pi%29%29) my $c_n$ using some examples in Mathematica with the [FourierCoefficient](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierCoefficient.html) function and they seemed to be correct.

I further wanted to check my $c_n$ by calculating an inverse fft and plotting them together with the original $x(k, \phi, t)$. But the results were not as expected.

Plot (blue is what was expected and red the result from IFFT) with $\phi=0.0$ and $k = 8.5$:
[image: Plot with phi=0.0 and k = 8.5:]

Plot with $\phi=0.3$ and $k = 8$:
[image: Plot with phi=0.3 and k=8]

Plot with $\phi=0.3$ and $k = 8.3$:
[image: Plot with phi=0.3 and k=8]

For reference my matlab code is:

```
k = 8.3; %number of oscillations per period
phi = 0.3; %phase in radians

t = linspace(0,511,512);
n = linspace(-1,-255,255);
fft_coeff0 = 256*(exp(i*phi)*sinc(-k)+exp(-i*phi)*sinc(k));
fft_coeffs(1:255) = 256*(exp(i*phi)*sinc(n-k)+exp(-i*phi)*sinc(n+k));

reconst_fft = [fft_coeff0 fft_coeffs 0 conj(fft_coeffs(end:-1:1))];

y = cos(k/512*2*pi*t+phi);
plot(t, ifft(reconst_fft), 'r', t, y, 'b')
```

What could cause the difference between my expected output and the IFFT? How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the sum formula $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$ and compute the Fourier coefficients on just the part with the variables.

Comment: Do I get it right that I should transform $\cos(2 \pi \frac{k}{T}+\phi) = \cos(2 \pi \frac{k}{T})\cos(\phi)-\sin(2 \pi \frac{k}{T})\sin(\phi)$ and then calculate the fourier coefficients $c_{n,1}$ for $\cos(2 \pi \frac{k}{T})$ and $c_{n,2}$ for $\sin(2 \pi \frac{k}{T})$ and then get $c_n = \cos(\phi)c_{n,1}-\sin(\phi)c_{n,2}$?